# Farm tractor implementation

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have a code which was not refactored at all. I refactored it to some extent, but stuck at a point where I cannot think of anything further.

**Tractor.java:**

```
package com.farm;

public class Tractor implements MethodsInterface {

    private int[] position;

    private int[] field;

    private String orientation;

    public Tractor(){
        position  = new int[]{0,0};
        field = new int[]{5,5};
        orientation = "N";
    }

    public void move(String command) {
        if(command=="F"){
            moveForwards();
        }else if(command=="T"){
            turnClockwise();
        }
    }

    private void moveForwards() {
        if(orientation=="N"){
            position = new int[]{position[0], position[1]+1}; 
        } else if(orientation == "E"){ 
            position = new int[]{position[0]+1, position[1]}; 
        } else if(orientation == "S"){ 
            position = new int[]{position[0], position[1]-1}; 
        }else if(orientation == "W"){ 
            position = new int[]{position[0]-1, position[1]}; 
        } 
        if(position[0] > field[0] || position[1] > field[1]) {
            try {
                throw new TractorInDitchException();
            } catch (TractorInDitchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void turnClockwise() {
        if(orientation=="N"){
            orientation = "E";
        }else if(orientation == "E"){
            orientation = "S";
        }else if(orientation == "S"){
            orientation = "W";
        }else if(orientation == "W"){
            orientation = "N";
        }
    }


    public int getPositionX() {
        return position[0];
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return position[1];
    }

    public String getOrientation() {
        return orientation;
    }
}
```

**TractorInDitchException.java:**

```
package com.farm;

public class TractorInDitchException extends Exception{

}
```

**MethodsInterface.java:**

```
package com.farm;

public interface MethodsInterface {

    public int getPositionX();
    public int getPositionY();
    public String getOrientation();
}
```

What else could be refactored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Instead of magic constants like `"N"`, `"S"` etc. use an enum which contains named constants and their values are checked on compile time.

   ```
   public enum Orientation {
     NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
   }
   ```

   With plain `String`s it's too easy to set an invalid value to the `orientation` field.
2. You can move the `turnClockwise` method to an enum:

   ```
   public enum Orientation {
     NORTH {
       @Override
       public Orientation turnClockwise() {
         return EAST;
       }
     },
     SOUTH {
       @Override
       public Orientation turnClockwise() {
         return WEST;
       }
     },
     WEST {
       @Override
       public Orientation turnClockwise() {
         return NORTH;
       }
     },
     EAST {
       @Override
       public Orientation turnClockwise() {
         return SOUTH;
       }
     };

     public abstract Orientation turnClockwise();

   }
   ```

   It increases [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and [replaces conditional with polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

   (I'd also try to create a `Position` class with `x` and `y` coordinates and move the statements from the `moveForwards` method to this class like `goNorth()`, `goWest()` etc. Then a new `Position moveForward(Position current)` method in the `Orientation` enum would call one of the `Position.go*()` methods.)
3. I'd change this array:

   ```
   position = new int[] {0, 0};
   ```

   to two ints:

   ```
   private int positionX;
   private int positionY;
   ```

   Indexes here (`0` and `1`) are [magic constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants).
4. The `moveForwards` and the the `Tractor` class looks unfinished. Noone writes the `field` array.
5. This:

   ```
   try {
     throw new TractorInDitchException();
   } catch (final TractorInDitchException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   could be written as

   ```
   new TractorInDitchException().printStackTrace();
   ```

   without the `try-catch` structure. A logger framework (for example SLFJ and Logback) would be better here.
6. What should happen when the tractor reach the border of the field? (When the index is negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.)

Comment: +1 for a great thorough answer.  Further to #2, I'd move the `Orienation` enum out of the `Tractor` class so that is available for the any future classes that may need it (such as `FieldCar` or `SheepDog`).

Comment: Thanks, @RobertGowland! I agree. Actually, I don't like inner classes too much, so one file per class/enum/interface is the default for me :-)

Comment: Is the tractor being in the ditch really an exception case while running the code? In other words, it seems proper to use the State concept then forcing the VM to dump the current stack if the tractor moves somewhere that causes problems.

Answer (score 6):

First, the code compares Strings using `==`. This will compare the *reference* rather than the contents of the String. Use [`String.compareTo(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [`String.compareToIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Better yet, do not use a `String` as an argument in your `move()` method. It would be ideal to use an `enum`, but a char will do as well. The same holds for your variable `orientation`.

`MethodsInterface` is not a very descriptive name. It seems to describe the location and orientation of objects, so consider a more descriptive name. Maybe `SpatialInfo`.

`Position` is an array of `int`s. It seems to be 2-dimensional, so consider the use of `Point`. In fact, I would prefer a `Point` or `Position` class above an array whether you use 2D or 3D.

I'm not sure why your `TractorInDitchException` is an `Exception`. Exceptions are used for handling exceptional situations in program flow. I imagine that your tractor ending up in a ditch, although *not* an everyday situation on your simulated farm, should be covered by the regular program flow.

There's not much point in having a try-catch block around a single `throw` operation anyway, when the only point of the try-catch block is to catch the very `Exception` that you're deliberately throwing.

A message to the user, and perhaps some kind of flag on the Tractor object that it is in the ditch, would be more useful.

If all you want is the stack trace, you can use `new Throwable().printStackTrace()` (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)).